# how to change TabPage Change

Tags: c#, tabcontrol

How can I change my current tab by click button event?

```
public void btn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        { 
//change tab here  

        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
tabCtrl.SelectedTab = desiredTab;
```

or

```
tabCtrl.SelectedIndex = desiredTabIndex;
```